# Replace the sine of small angles sine by the angle

Tags: matlab

In mathematics we can assume that `sin(t1)` is equal to `t1` for very small angles. How to do that in Matlab?

```
syms t1;
res = sin(t1);
res2= MAGIC(res,t1);
```

I need `MAGIC`to change `res`, such that it becomes `t1`.

Thanks

Comment: You can assume it in math because when you do it in matlab,  they are almost equal.

Comment: how to change it so?, i need this MAGIC to make my equation linear!

Comment: Just write `res2 = t1` or do I oversee something?

Comment: @Matt you are very intelligent! i have the `sin(t1)` in a complex equation and it is result of a `diff` function! how to change it there?

Comment: change it here `k*t1 + (k*(2*t1 - 2*t2))/2 - a*p*sin(t1)`

Comment: I suggest writing `k*t1 + (k*(2*t1 - 2*t2))/2 - a*p*t1` if you can. Otherwise you need to overload the built-in `sin`.

Comment: If you do this, you should do it as @Matt suggests, or if you are using symbolic maths, as @hbaderts told you. DO NOT create a function `MAGIC` that does that for small numbers, because if there is suddlenly a bigger number you will introduce a big non-linearity to the equation.

Comment: Are you working with symbolic maths? The guess is that you do since such an approximation is not needed for numerical equations. Numerical equations does not bother whether the equation is stated to be `sin(x)` instead of `x`. It only bother about 0.000521319 or 0.000521320. This is as good as equal in numerical methods since there are other things which can do as much or more damage to the accuracy. So i you work with symbols, please tell us that! The methods and equations are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small angle assumption comes from a [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansion to linearize `sin(x)` about `a = 0` and ignoring higher order terms (n >= 2). If you have a more complex equation and wish to linearize it about a set point, the symbolic math toolbox is great for that task. Simply use the [taylor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/taylor.html) function. For your simple case:

```
syms a b x
res1 = a + b*sin(x);
res2 = taylor(res1, x, 0, 'Order', 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`subs`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) function is your friend. It allows to substitute any symbolic expressions.

For example:

```
syms a b x
eq1 = a + b*sin(x);
eq2 = subs(eq1,sin(x),x);    % Replace sin(x) by x
```

which results in

```
eq2 =
     a + b*x
```